Get more than 1000 records from Matillion Task History API
I am using Matillion Task History API to fetch the history of tasks that have been running in the Matillion ETL instance. Task history results are subject to a limit of 1,000 records for a single task run. I was looking if there is pagination support for this particular API endpoint but seems like it doesn't support pagination.
Is there any way I can get more than 1000 records?

Does adding a ?since=yyyy-mm-dd parameter help? I'm wondering if you loop backwards day by day, it will still be capped at 1000 each time, but as long as you don't have >1000 jobs in a single day you'll eventually get them all, and you'll be able to deduplicate on the id afterwards.

@53epo, no, it does not give more than 1000 records no matter which date you use with ?since=yyyy-mm-dd parameter.

That's annoying. The problem with it is the API always returns the latest tasks first. So if you have >1000 tasks altogether, the API always returns the most recent 1000 regardless of the since parameter. I was hoping it would return the oldest tasks first. I don't see a way around this problem with the API.
